# Regular expression not producing the intended output

Tags: regex, lex

I am making a simple regular expression to recognise first consonant(if any),then all the vowels in between and then the next consonant after the last vowel(if any).

For ex:

```
we are all morons -->> we ae al moon
```

I wrote this expression but it doesn't work in all situations.

Please advise.

```
"[^aeiou]?[aeiou]+[aeiou]?"
```

Not sure where I am getting wrong.

Comment: Recognize? You want to capture them? In that case use capturing groups `()`. Also instead of writing `[^aeiou]` you should list all consonants because the negated vowels match other things than letters as well. (And what that leading `?` is doing there I don't know.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use non capturing groups so the matching wont halt. Now you are matching only words that matches your desired output. see : [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group)
for more information.